# Problem after trying to connect with database

Tags: sql, r, database

The German text says the data source name was not found and no default driver was specified.

Being fairly new to programming in R, I have absolutely no idea how to fix the problem.
The database query is supposed to fill an Excel, which is output empty due to the error.
The error does not occur with my colleagues, but no one can explain why it is the case with me.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcH21.png)

Comment: First, please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly. Second, it could be that you do not have the [Access/Excel odbc driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) installed. I don't know RODBC, but see if `odbcDataSources()` lists an access/excel odbc connection (that may not be definitive).

Comment: (It looks as if you have an idea what the drivers are based on the presence of `sDriverName`, but I can't be certain.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `connectDB` function looks like something created inhouse. Try stepping through it to see if you can get more details on the error. It is possible that you PC has not been setup for the ODBC connection, or some other environment variable is missing on your machine.